# How to switch between different azure resources with zero downtime?

Tags: azure

I want to migrate my server from azure app service to kubernetes with zero downtime. How is it possible? I have a custom domain. Website is containerized using docker. And i want to seamlessly redirect the web requests from app service to kubernetes.

Comment: why not just add the TLS certificate to k8s and switch the DNS record the kubernetes endpoint? alternatively you could put an application gateway in front and handle TLS/DNS at the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, its really easy, one just has to make the configure the new resouce accept incoming request from the custom domain and then make the custom domain point to the new resource.

I was confusued because I thought one has to validate domain ownership everytime one configures custom domain in azure.